# Pyspark - Fill blank months with 0 in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Disclaimer: I've very new to pyspark

I've grouped my dataframe on the `id` and `month_year` to get total counts of how much a user engages with your product. Now this issue is months with no activity are now showing up my final df.

This is how its done:

```
app_sessions_per_month = app_sessions.where("session_start_date_pt > '2019-05-25'").groupby('id','month_year').agg(F.sum('action').alias('count'))

+--------------------+----------+----------------------+
|             core_id|month_year|month_sum_detailaction|
+--------------------+----------+----------------------+
|aa01bb6f-2dd8-43e...|    7_2019|                     0|
|aa01bb6f-2dd8-43e...|    9_2019|                     0|
|aa01bb6f-2dd8-43e...|   10_2019|                     0|
+--------------------+----------+----------------------+
```

The dates actually go from `05_2019` to `05_2020`.

Original DF:

```
id month_year count
1. 02_2020.   1
1. 03_2020.   4
1. 05_2020.   2
1. 06_2020.   7
1. 07_2020.   2
```

Desired DF:

```
id month_year count
1. 01_2020.   0
1. 02_2020.   1
1. 03_2020.   4
1  04_2020.   0
1. 05_2020.   2
1. 06_2020.   7
1. 07_2020.   2
```

Now this example just shows 1 `id` but my actual dataset has millions of ids

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can we assume there could multiple missing months between 2 rows, and what is ur spark version?

Comment: Could you please put a sample view of your original data and the way you aggregate your result so that we can have a better understanding of the processes you are doing?

Comment: @SasanAhmadi - Added edits

Comment: from ur updated set, it seems that u want to handle 2 cases, the start should be from 1 month, and wherever in the middle there are missing to add them, and do nothing to the end 07-2020, correct me if im wrong @MadhavThaker

Comment: As @murtihash mentioned, there are two issues you have to resolve. I assume you meant group by "core_id" which is not in the code. So, for the first issue which is missing months, you have to generate a list of missing months and combine the result! because once you do a group by there is no way back and probably you have no data for those missing months! for the Id column, as far as I know, there should not be anything wrong from spark side! could you provide a simple test case for this which shows the problem clearly?